Abstract ribbon
I'm trying to model an abstract ribbon like this. I can extrude it as a flat face with a Bezier, but I'd also like the thickness - thicker and flat on the bottom so that it can lay flat, and coming to a ridge at the top.
Thanks, any help appreciated.

You want it to be a 3-dimensional object, you mean?

Do you talk about the brown ridge ? The one that seems sometimes tangent to the main surface (at the far left e.g.), and sometimes perpendicular (at the far right) ? It looks like a sine/cosine "thing", so GeometryNodes might help. Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Yes, I'm trying to design this as a 3D mesh.
